# How to retrieve AssetReference from Scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Scene marked as Addressable. Given the `Scene` itself, is it possible to get the `AssetReference` for that scene?

For example, in the following code snippet, what would `??` need to be?

```cs
Scene activeScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

// What can I call here to get the AssetReference?
AssetReference activeSceneReference = ??;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is possible at all I honetsly can't tell since I never worked with Addressables so far.

However, following the APIs this might be possible but requires multiple steps:

Since the `activeScene` is a loaded scene and the same scene can be loaded multiple times via additive loading it is not actually an asset anymore and therefore doesn't have an asset reference at all.

---

So the first step is actually

**Get the asset for a loaded scene**

Having your loaded scene you can still get its original asset path via [`Scene.path`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-path.html).

```c#
var activeScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
var activeScenePath = activeScene.path;
```

And then use [`AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html) to load the original asset

```c#
var activeSceneAsset = AssetDataBase.LoadAssetAtPath<Scene>(activeScenePath);
```

---

Now that we have the actual **asset** of the loaded scene we can

**Get the GUID of an Asset**

Having already the asset `activeSceneAsset` you can use [`AssetDatabase.TryGetGUIDAndLocalFileIdentifier`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.TryGetGUIDAndLocalFileIdentifier.html) in order to optain the GUID we need in the last step:

```c#
if (AssetDatabase.TryGetGUIDAndLocalFileIdentifier(activeSceneAsset, out var guid, out var file))
{
    // TODO see below
}
```

---

and now having that `guid` we can use it in order to

**Get the `AssetReference` via the GUID**

The reason why we wanted to get the GUID is because we can now use it for the [`AssetReference` constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@0.4/api/UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.AssetReference.html#constructors) taking the GUID as parameter:

```c#
var activeSceneReference = new AssetReference(guid);
```

---

**NOTE:** All this is ofcourse only possible in the Unity Editor itself since `AssetDataBase` does not exist outside of it.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough answer!

This is great in that it returns _an_ AssetReference, but I should have clarified that I’m trying to get the already-existing  Asset Reference for the scene (the same one that you’d get if you dragged the Scene into an AssetReference slot in the inspector). My understanding is that there’s just one AssetReference that can be used to spawn any number of versions of the same scene, and I was hoping there’d be some way to point back to that original AssetReference.

Comment: Also, if it helps: the use case here is a cold start from levels in a game. The normal flow in my game uses the AssetReference to load up scenes, and this flow keeps that AssetReference around for bookkeeping. When starting the game in the middle of a level (when developing/debugging), the scene is already loaded and I don’t have a handle to the AssetReference. There are manual workarounds, but I was hoping to be able to grab that AssetReference programmatically on play.

Comment: Update: this works, actually! After creating a new AssetReference you can compare the `assetReference.editorAsset`. Thanks a ton @derHugo